# ScalaMock mocking a trait gives "MockFunction1 cannot be cast to StubFunction1"

Tags: scala, scalamock

The following code:

```
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

trait SomeTrait {
  def getLongByInt(int: Int): Long
}

class TestScalaMock extends FlatSpec with MockFactory {
  "Scala Mock" should "mock my trait" in {
    val someTrait = mock[SomeTrait]
    (someTrait.getLongByInt _) when (1) returns 2L
    assert(2L == someTrait.getLongByInt(1))
  }
}
```

Gives me a runtime error `org.scalamock.MockFunction1 cannot be cast to org.scalamock.StubFunction1`. My project dependencies are:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.7",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.7",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.1" % "test",
  "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.2" % "test"
  )
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

ScalaMock supports two different styes—expectation-first and record-then-verify (Mockito-style).

For expectation-first, use `mock` to create the fake object and `expects` to set expectations.

For record-then-verify, use `stub` to create the fake object, `when` to setup return values and `verify` to verify calls.

In your code you're using `mock` (expectations-first) together with `when` (record-then-verify). Use `expects` instead, and you should be fine.

(note, you can mix different styles within a single test, but not for a single fake object).

Comment: seems odd that it has two different objects rather than one; at first glance it seems that `mock` is write-only. am i missing something as to why this is?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "write-only"? If there is a way to have a single type of fake object support both mocking styles, I'd love to hear it, but it's not clear to me how this could be achieved right now.

Comment: It would be great if there were some way for this type of problem to be caught at compile time rather than at runtime. But the compile-time type of the `mock[SomeTrait]` and `stub[SomeTrait]` expressions must be `SomeTrait`. If it weren't, ScalaMock wouldn't be doing what a mocking framework is supposed to do.
However, I wonder if it might be possible for the ScalaMock framework to identify at runtime when the programmer has made this mistake and put a helpful suggestion in the Exception's message?